# Is it common to say 'not that urgent'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases, slang, conversation

Is it correct to say ‘not that urgent’ to someone who is offering urgent appointment thinking that there is something urgent?

Comment: It is idiomatic.  How common it is, I can't say.  In many places, if it's your boss asking, the response is "I''ll get right on it!"

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what does “ I’ll get right on it” mean?

Comment: "I will attend to it right away!"